# Returning a value from a Room database using Jetpack Compose

Tags: sqlite, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

Hello and thank you for considering my question!  I'm trying to query a database for a sum and display the total with a Jetpack Compose UI.

My DAO looks like this:

```
@Dao
interface FindDao {


    @Query("SELECT SUM(findAmount) FROM finds")
    suspend fun getFindTotal(): Double

}
```

My Repository looks like this:

```
class FindRepository (private val findDao: FindDao) {

 private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)


suspend fun getFindTotal():Double {
        return findDao.getFindTotal()

    }

    }
```

My Viewmodel looks like this:

```
class MainViewModel(application: Application): ViewModel() {

suspend fun getFindTotal(): Double {
        return repository.getFindTotal()
    }


}
```

And lastly my UI looks like:

```
@Composable
fun BottomBar(viewModel: MainViewModel) {
    val scope_Find_Total = rememberCoroutineScope()
    var retrievedFindTotal by remember { mutableStateOf<Double?>(null) }

    scope_Find_Total.launch {
        retrievedFindTotal = viewModel.getFindTotal()
    }


   Text("Find Total = $retrievedFindTotal")
}
```

So, this code works but I think I'm doing this wrong, I'm getting a warning "Calls to launch should happen inside a LaunchedEffect and not composition".  Furthermore, I think maybe I shouldn't be launching co-routines from my UI?  Not sure if I'm going about this properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it in the `ViewModel` and expose a `State<Double?>` as a more idiomatic solution.

ViewModel:

```
    private val _findTotal = mutableStateOf<Double?>(null)
    val findTotal: State<Double?> = _findTotal

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _findTotal.value = repository.getFindTotal()
        }
    }
```

Composable:

```
val findTotal by viewModel.findTotal

Text("Find Total = $findTotal")
```

Answer (score 1):

The warning actually gives a fairly good hint. Try to change your code to

```
@Composable
fun BottomBar(viewModel: MainViewModel) {
    val scope_Find_Total = rememberCoroutineScope()
    var retrievedFindTotal by remember { mutableStateOf<Double?>(null) }

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        retrievedFindTotal = viewModel.getFindTotal()
    }

    Text("Find Total = $retrievedFindTotal")
}
```

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#remembercoroutinescope), `rememberCoroutineScope()` should be used primarily when a couroutine needs to be called outside of a Composable function.

Besides that, I consider your architecture to be typical for such a use case. It is perfectly fine to trigger a ViewModel data loading function from a `LaunchedEffect` inside of a Composable. However you should consider if it would be preferable to eagerly load the data at the time of the ViewModel initialization. This depends on how your ViewModel is scoped and how much data you are requesting. See the answer by @Janitor for a way how to eagerly load data into the ViewModel.